# is public static sql connection secure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I am working on a windows service in c#, and perhaps I might use the same methods in my web application if it works. The main service is using a sqlconnection that is used for itself, retrieved from app.config using ConfigurationManager, and it creates a few threads of different types, to run several tasks. Each of these threads has its own connection (stored in class property).

```
public partial class MainService : ServiceBase{
    private static string SQLConnStr;
    protected static SqlConnection SQLConn;
}

class OtherClass{
    private sqlconnection sqlconn;
    private string connstr;

}
```

The part that I am stuck with, is that, when I create another object type, I need that object to be able to access the DB using OtherClass' connection. This new object is created and called in OtherClass for processing later on.

Is it possible to re-use the sql connection from OtherClass?
Is it safe and secure to make the sql connection string as public static?
Is the design I am using not good?

Comment: The best practice is to put your connection string in Web.config file.

Comment: The answer you want depends on the situation. If its a class library, everything will be compiled into a DLL. In that case it someone using that DLL will be able to access your connection string too (if it is public). This is not secure, I think.

Comment: u mean if I put the classes in a dll, it doesn't matter if it's private or public?

Comment: I forget to mention that the connection string is retrieved from the app.config file into SQLConnStr and connstr.

Comment: Kindly note the edit in my comment and also include the above information in the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I like your answers, but mine is the case of bad design, after looking into it a while. So I decided to create a public static query function in the MainService:

```
public static void qQuery(string querystr){
    using(sqlconnection conn = new sqlconnection(sqlconnstr){
        .....
    }
}
```

sqlconnstr is a private string in MainService which is initialized when the service starts.

I hope it is safe and secure way of doing it...

Answer (score 2):

pass it to `OtherClass` constructor ?

**details with example**:

```
public partial class MainService : ServiceBase{
    private string SQLConnStr;
}

class OtherClass{
    private string connstr;
    public OtherClass(string _connstr) { this.connstr = _connstr; }
    public foo() { using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connstr) { ... } }
}
```

Creating `new SqlConnection` each time is fine in .NET since there is connection pool.

Comment: It would be a last resort. I would not prefer to do that.

Comment: @Heather : Lets see, how about others who have answered the same question, doesn't it seems that yours is kind of an odd man out ? It seems based on your arguments under your answer I would expect you to understand that more people differ in a way that you thought that as an answer like that suits. You said `pass it to OtherClass constructor ?` now was that a question or an answer seems confusing to a 3rd person doesn't it

Comment: @Heather : Regarding the improvement of the answer how about an example like a method call passing the instance to a constructor would have added a little more on what your trying to say. Now I have also seen the answers that you made and those all seems fine and good to be considered but this doesn't, and what every one and me is trying to explain you is that if you have a one liner which is not a code I would suggest you to add it as a comment rather than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the respective configuration mechanism. For applications/windows services this would bee the `app.config` file, for web applications it would be the `web.config` file and for DLLs, the settings should be copied from the DLL's `app.config` to the application's `app.config/web.config` as described here many times (DLLs don't read their config files, so the settings need to go into the application's config file).

That being said: Use the settings designer in Visual Studio to simply add a new connection string setting. If necessary, add it to other projects, too.

To use the connection string from class within the same project, you can then simply use `Settings.Default.MyConnectionString` assuming that the setting is named `MyConnectionString`.

Another exception for DLLs: Some DLLs don't need their own settings, but they need to access a database. In that case you could pass the connection string or even an `SqlConnection` to the function that requires database access.

Comment: I know. What I was after was to just rely on the standard settings mechanism and then use that setting throughout the code or pass it to DLLs. I read the question, you know? :D

Answer (score 1):

There is a distinction between connection*string* and the connection itself. For the connectionstring (describing where you should connect to), you can store that in a config file so youu can easily change it.

The connection itself that is used to communicate with the database must be opened and closed. When you use datareaders, you can't usually use the same connection for simultaneous commands.
It is best to open a new connection as late as possible and close it as soon as possible. Let the built-in connectionpooling do it's thing to optimize the real connections.